# multiple producers and consumers by using multi-threading in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got stuck in this question about multiple producers-consumers question. My goal is to write six threads to act as A, B,...,F, and let the program keep printing forever.

Please click here for the image:[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtoNF.png)

Each pair of nodes associated with an arrow correspond to a producers-consumers pair (or say **buffer**). The buffer size is **2** and initially, only A is in possession of 2 tokens.
I've already tried A -> B -> D ->F. The code is as below:

```
class Cookies   
{
    private int cookiesNo;
    private int buffer=0;

    public synchronized void put (int cNo, String sender, String receiver)
    {
        while (buffer==2)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){}
        }
        System.out.println(sender+" put the "+cNo+"th cookie to "+receiver);
        cookiesNo= cNo;
        buffer++;
        notify();
    }
    public synchronized void eat (int cNo, String sender, String receiver)
    {
        while (buffer==0)
        {
            try {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){}
        }
        System.out.println(sender+" put the "+cNo+"th cookie to "+receiver);
        cookiesNo= cNo;
        buffer--;
        notify();
    }
}
```

```
class DPut implements Runnable  
{
    Cookies cookies;
    DPut(Cookies cookies)
    {
        this.cookies=cookies;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i=1; i<=10000; i++)
        {
            cookies.put(i, "D", "F");
        }
    }
}
class DEat implements Runnable  //human
{
    Cookies cookies;
    DEat(Cookies cookies)
    {
        this.cookies=cookies;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i=1; i<=10000; i++)
        {
            cookies.eat(i, "B", "D");
        }
    }
}
class APut implements Runnable  
{
    Cookies cookies;
    APut(Cookies cookies)
    {
        this.cookies=cookies;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i=1; i<=100; i++)
        {
            cookies.put(i, "A", "B");
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class practice
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Cookies cookies= new Cookies();
        DPut dput= new DPut(cookies);
        DEat deat= new DEat(cookies);
        APut aput= new APut(cookies);
        Thread ddog= new Thread(deat);
        Thread dmaster= new Thread(dput);
        Thread amaster= new Thread(aput);

        amaster.start();
        ddog.start();
        dmaster.start();

    }
}
```

Output(I screenshot the beginning and the middle):

[click1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBdAN.png)    [click2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Hg5.png)

I tried to think it as master(producer), dog(consumer) and cookie(product). The master puts the cookie and the dog eats it.

My problems are:

1. The output looks like the first picture(AtoB & BtoD) in the beginning 100 cookies. Then it turned to picture two (BtoD & DtoF) until 10 thousand. How can I fix that? I want it to get AtoB running too, but it just stopped...
2. I don't know how to start on A and F, since they have two ins or two outs.
3. Is my strategy right? I wrote the code based on the single producer-consumer scenario.

I'm new to multi-threading so please tell me my mistakes.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, although 'synchronized' is still valid for mutex, it is 15 years obsolete for signalling. If you want to do wait/notify, use reentrant locks and conditions await/signal[All].

Notify() only wakes 1 thread, and that maybe well be the wrong thread because you don't have any condition for the signal. The last put thread setting the buffer to 2 (full) might notify another put thread, then no more notify occurs to wake a eater.

The old way would be to use notifyAll(), and that would work although would wake up everyone and cause a lot of contention to acquire the synchronized for nothing except for one or two thread. That's why you should prefer reentrant lock with 2 conditions (not empty/notfull).

It's pretty much the basics behind an arrayblockingqueue.